# Clojure, reduce function. Error: Don't know how to create ISeq

Tags: clojure

When I executed this code

```
(reduce (fn [final number] (into final (+ number 1))) [] [1 2 3 4 5])
```

I got this error:

> Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long

Comment: Unless this is for learning, it's way shorter to write: `(mapv inc [1 2 3 4 5])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `conj` instead of `into`.

`into` appends a sequence, `conj` appends an element.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can wrap `(+ number 1)` with *vector* but using `conj` would be proper one:

```
(reduce (fn [final number] (into final [(+ number 1)])) [] [1 2 3 4 5])
```